# Unix shell bash script unable to put an echo debug statement

Tags: shell, makefile

I have the following make file, which i think is a shell script.

I am trying to loop through `FILE_DIR` to perform some operations. However, i feel that the implementation isn't working as expected. So i am trying to insert some `echo` breakpoints.

Source:

```
# Target to recurse through the DIR_LIST and make each makefile found in that DIRS
ALLDIRS:
       for se in $(FILE_DIR); do \
              if [ -d $se ]; then \
              cd $se; \
              $(MAKE) -f Makefile.mk all; \
              cd ..; \
              fi \
       done
```

Running:

```
$ make -f Makefile.batch

h: syntax error at line 3: `then' unexpected
*** Error code 2
The following command caused the error:
for se in `ls -p /app/internal|grep "/"`; do \
        echo "Test" \
        if [ -d e ]; then \
        cd e; \
        /usr/ccs/bin/make -f Makefile.mk all; \
        cd ..; \
        fi \
done
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `ALLDIRS'
```

Can i please get help on this. Would like to insert an `echo` breakpoint.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your `echo` statement, but your `if` statement is different between the two versions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Try a simpler command.

Comment: @tjameson The second version is the output from make and shows perfectly the second point in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

One common error in `Makefile`s is using spaces instead of tabs in a command line. Check the whole `for` loop and make sure there are only tabs at the beginning of each line

```
ALLDIRS:
<tab>for se in $(FILE_DIR); do \
<tab><tab>if [ -d $se ]; then \
<tab><tab>cd $se; \
<tab><tab>$(MAKE) -f Makefile.mk all; \
<tab><tab>cd ..; \
<tab><tab>fi \
<tab>done
```

Another error is the dollar sign `$`. If you want a dollar sign in the shell command, you must double it in your commands, because otherwise dollar introduces a *make variable* and will be expanded before the shell sees it.

```
for se in $(FILE_DIR); do \
    if [ -d $$se ]; then \
        cd $$se; \
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.mk all; \
        cd ..; \
    fi \
done
```

And the final one, `echo Test` needs a semicolon as well

```
for se in $(FILE_DIR); do \
    if [ -d $$se ]; then \
        echo "Test"; \
        cd $$se; \
...
```

Comment: A <TAB> is necessary only at the beginning of each *command*. The other eleven are internal to the command, and unneeded.

Comment: @Beta It's not necessary, but a good habit. So you're not tempted to skip it, *when* necessary.